# Iframe background

Tags: iframe, background

On my website I have a page with a standard background.  I want this page to load in an iframe without the background from the original page in another section of my site.  Is this possible?  What is the syntax for this if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure the iframe is big enough in order to hide the background.

Are you trying to hijack the address? If so, you should use redirects and not iframes.